# finding the area of a circle using diameter input / Def functions

Tags: python, function

I am trying to find the area of a circle in sq. using diameter input. I feel like Im not to far away from getting it correct. The program opens but closes after excepting an input. This my code so far
This is my code so far ..

```
def circleArea(diameter_of_the_circle):
    radius = diameter / 2
    pi = 3.14159
    result = pi * radius * radius
    return(result)

dt = float(input("\nEnter the diameter of the circle in cms: "))

anwser = circleArea(diameter_of_the_circle)

print("\nThe Area of the circle is:", anwser)

input("\nPress Enter to exit")
```

Comment: Use anwser = circleArea(dt)

Comment: what if i changed 'dt' to diameter_of_the_circle ?? @user19077881

Comment: That works too. You just have to be consistent in your variable names. If you assign the variable from the input, use that in the function call.

Comment: You should have gotten an error from your version, telling you that `diameter_of_the_circle` is not defined.

Comment: Run your script in a terminal window rather than popping up a new window for it, because the latter method closes the window automatically and you never see the errors.

Comment: You shouldn't use Python 2.x, it was EOL several years ago, unless you require it for legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgot to use the same name as the input parameter.

```
import math

def circleArea(diameter):
    radius = diameter / 2
    result = math.pi * radius * radius
    return(result)

dt = float(input("\nEnter the diameter of the circle in cms: "))

anwser = circleArea(dt)

print("\nThe Area of the circle is:", anwser)

input("\nPress Enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. in your function definition, the argument is `diameter_of_the_circle` and then you have `radius = diameter / 2`. what is `diameter`?
2. you defines `dt` but then used `diameter_of_the_circle` as the function input.